# which of following option is correct for heat equation (CSIR june 2018)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

If $u(x,t)$ is the solution to
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^2}~, \quad 0<x<1,~t>0 \\
u(x,0) = 1 + x + \sin(\pi x) \cos(\pi x)~, \quad u(0,t)=1,~u(1,t)=2$$
then

> 1).$u(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4})=\frac{3}{2}$
>
> 2).$u(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})=\frac{3}{2}$
>
> 3).$u(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4})=\frac{5}{4}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-3\pi^{2}}$
>
> 4).$u(\frac{1}{4},1)=\frac{5}{4}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-4\pi^{2}}$

I tried to solve this question: we know that solution of such equation is of the type: $$( c_1 \cos\lambda x + c_2 \sin\lambda x )\cdot c_3 e^{-\lambda^2 t}$$

but how can we get that $x$ in the solution equation?

It seems very complicated. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, find the **steady-state solution** $w(x)$, which satisfies

$$ \frac{d^2 w}{dx^2} = 0, \quad w(1) = 1, w(2) = 2 $$

this gives $w(x) = 1 + x$

Next, we have

$$ u(x,t) = 1 + x + v(x,t) $$

where $v(x,t)$ also solves the heat equation, but is homogeneous on the boundary, i.e. $v(0,t)=v(1,t)=0$. Performing separation of variables on $v(x,t)$ gives the general solution

$$ u(x,t) = 1 + x + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin(n\pi x)e^{-n^2\pi^2 t} $$

For a multiple choice question, you need to get this quick, so it may be helpful to memorize that **Dirichlet B.C.s = sine series in $x$.**

The initial condition is

$$ u(x,0) = 1 + x + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin(n\pi x) = 1 + x + \frac12 \sin(2\pi x) $$

which you can compare terms to get $a_2 = \frac12$, and $a_n=0$ for $n\ne 2$.

Altogether, the final solution is

$$ u(x,t) = 1 + x + \frac12 \sin(2\pi x)e^{-4\pi^2 t} $$

which gives

$$ u\left(\frac12, \frac14\right) = \frac32 $$

Comment: why are we using steady state solution?,and how w(1)=1,w(2)=2?

Comment: @gauravsaini You need it to match the original boundary conditions

Comment: thnx ,for your answer but still i don't know why we use steady state solution,when does we apply this condition.

Comment: @gauravsaini The goal is to eventually use separation of variables. But we can't use SoV while the boundary conditions are inhomogeneous. The steady-state exists to subtract off those B.C.s

Comment: Once again thank you,now i got it

Comment: But still i have to do lots of work to fully understand it.